# libepoxy's autogen can't find xorg-macros when prefix is /usr/local

Tags: gcc, autotools

libepoxy1.5.4 blames:

```
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I m4
configure.ac:36: error: must install xorg-macros 1.8 or later...
```

**This happens ONLY if XORG and LIBEPOXY installed in /usr/local.**

When /usr, then OK.

"pkgconfig xorg-macros" returns 0 (found it)

This file exists: usr/local/share/aclocal/xorg-macros.m4

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all surprised that `/usr/local/share/aclocal` is not in `aclocal`'s default macro search path when `aclocal` itself is installed in `/usr/bin`.  To the extent that xorg-macros seems to assume that its macros will be installed in `aclocal`'s systemwide macro directory, it is incorrect to install it under prefix /usr/local when aclocal is installed under prefix /usr.

If you want to persist with such a mismatch then you should be able to work around the issue by adding the xorg-macros's actual install directory to the macro search path.  You probably should do that by updating the `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS` variable in the top-level `Makefile.am`,

***from***

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
```

***to***

```
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4 -I /usr/local/share/aclocal
```

.

I am inclined to think that the destination directory for libepoxy is not relevant.

Comment: Most software use /usr/local by default. I just want to separate graphics/multimedia - x11... into /usr/local.
But there are more problems arose. They duplicate locales, as a result bash stops to understand bulk wildcard commands like "rm /usr/lib/*.la",
and it can't run gtk2/demo/Makefile:test-inline-pixbufs.h target.
Maybe linking /usr/local/share/aclocal[locales] -> /usr/share/aclocal[locales] resolves problems automatically, but I decided that using /usr/local is "time-wasting" way.

Comment: @YuryDemidenko, `/usr/local` is the Autotools' default prefix, and it is also the place designated for installing locally-built, unpackaged software.  But in this case, you're trying to install a separately-built add-on component of a larger system whose other pieces are installed in `/usr`, and which is not designed to be spread out over multiple prefixes.  Were it me, building for one of my usual RHEL or CentOS targets, I would build it *as an RPM*, targeting `/usr`.  Installing it via a package (which I would put in my local repository) satisfies me about using `/usr`.

Comment: <b>/lib(bin)</b> is for essential programs locally.
<b>/usr</b> is for distributed programs (from core vendor (Debian, OpenSuse) - received as deb/rpm packages), it maybe mapped from network.
<b>/usr/local</b> is for locally installed programs (usually from source).
<b>/opt</b> is for additional vendors e.g. chrome.deb/rpm.
HFS separates these to avoid upgrading conflicts.
I'm only vendor, and just wanted to separate numerous files(libs) (usr/local for gui, libreoffice...).
Of course, spreading static shared data like locales is not allowed.